# Facebook groups API access after app review approval

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Like many other developers, my FB app stopped working last week after Facebook blocked all apps using user_managed_groups permissions without review.

I have since submitted it for review. Has anyone been able to use user_managed_groups endpoint (groups/feed) after their app is approved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until further notice from Facebook, no one is able to access the Group API at the moment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes

> Testing of our more robust process starts today and the new process
>   should resume in a few weeks, but apps currently accessing Events and
>   Groups APIs will lose access today.

App Review is on pause. You can only wait until Facebook put it back on.